# Logic Apps - Get only the last failed logic app runs

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app with 10 stages, when runs get failed, I have a resubmit mechanism working in the logic app which resubmits the failed runs for a maximum of 5 attempts. But when I investigate the failed runs I get a total of 50 failed runs due to the retry mechanism(Actually failed runs is 10). How can I narrow my search to the 10 failed logic apps runs i.e, the last child runs?

Comment: How are you trying to do a resubmit/retry?

Comment: Using Azure Logic apps retry API from my custom-built application

Comment: To avoid your question being voted down, please add more details on how are you doing what you are doing.